# Outlook 2012 export for new mailbox

Tags: email, backup, microsoft-outlook, exchange

I'm using Outlook 2010 with my company's Exchange server, and I want to know about the export function; specifically, exporting the mailbox to a file.

I am wanting to move my mailbox from our Exchange server in Germany to our Exchange server in China, where I work. I want to know the following things:

1. If I export everything to a PST from my current mailbox, and then try and re-import that **after** I've created my mailbox on the China Exchange server, will that cause problems?
2. What information (besides emails themselves) gets carried over into the PST file?
3. If you import a PST file on your local computer, do those new messages (that don't exist on the server) get uploaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, Outlook 2010 allows you to connect to multiple Exchange accounts at once. You could open both in Outlook, and then move the items you want from the old account to the new account.

If you don't want to be selective, exporting/importing a PST is the best way. I went through a similar process when I "upgraded" my hosted Exchange plan from Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010. My provider is SherWeb, and [their instructions are basically to import/export the a PST for each mailbox](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-transfer-your-organization-from-sherweb-hosted-exchange-2007-to-sherweb-hosted-exchange-2010).

> If I export everything to a PST from my current mailbox, and then try and re-import that after I've created my mailbox on the China Exchange server, will that cause problems?

It shouldn't.

> What information (besides emails themselves) gets carried over into the PST file?

If you've got folders like Tasks, Contacts and Calendar in the PST then the contents of these folders will carry over, too.

> If you import a PST file on your local computer, do those new messages (that don't exist on the server) get uploaded?

If the account is associated with something like an Exchange account, it will. If it's an account associated with a POP mailbox then no.